# What's the difference between fetch (function in js) and socket io in web programming

Tags: javascript, web

I want to know if fetch can work as a replacement for sockets to get/send data between server and client? Also, can I use fetch to broadcast a message to all clients?

Comment: Define: "all clients".

Comment: By "socket" - do you mean **WebSockets**  or **Berkeley sockets** (aka BSD Sockets)? The two are very different things.

Comment: I mean web sockets

Comment: what i meant by"all clients": suppose i want to make a app like slack and i want to broadcast a new message in chat to all the members of the channel.

Comment: `fetch` is strictly client-to-server. WebSockets is bi-di but requires a central server. If you want peer-to-peer communication you'll want to use WebRTC instead, however WebRTC still needs a central server to coordinate clients.

Comment: I recommend you look at SignalR if you want to implement something like what you're describing - or some open-source WebRTC server like Kurento or EasyRTC.

Answer (score 0):

fetch is a method from the browser api to make http requests, can you use it to send requests to a backend service? yes. Do you want to implement websockets using fetch? then no. You should look into socket.io to know more of how it works

Comment: `socket.io` is a commerical third-party service and library that's comparable to SignalR. It is not about WebSockets (which is an open standard). You should link to the WebSocket spec instead.

Comment: I recommended these resources specifically if you want to learn more about WebSockets: https://tools.ietf.org/html/rfc6455 https://html.spec.whatwg.org/multipage/web-sockets.html https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/WebSockets_API/Writing_WebSocket_servers

Comment: so, if i want to add chat box to my project then I should use socket.io right?

Comment: It really depends on the application that you want, how many users it will have, how many resources you have, is for a company or just a personal project? if you want a serverless chat you can google WebRTC, you can use google stun servers to avoid writing any backend logic. On the opposite, if the app is going to be bigger, then yes, i would go with socket.io or write my own sockets